# Virtual host misconfiguration with xampp on ubuntu

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, xampp, virtualhost

I have Linux Ubuntu 13.10LTS installed on my computer with XAMPP 1.8.2. I am trying to add a virtual host and I am done. But when i enter `www.example.com` in the address bar it shows `www.example.com/xampp` which is not desired by me.
below is the configurations I used to create that:

`httpd-vhosts.conf:`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin root@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html/
    ServerName www.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

`/etc/hosts:`

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   mustafa-Latitude-E5430-vPro
127.0.1.1   www.portal.com
```

what is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `www.example.com` to your `/etc/hosts` file:

```
127.0.1.1   www.example.com
```

Comment: I added it, if you look at my question

Comment: I can't see it anywhere in your `hosts` file? Only `localhost`, `mustafa-Latitude-E5430-vPro` and `www.portal.com`. There's no `www.example.com`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Allow the usage of custom virtual hosts

> sudo gedit /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf

2. Uncomment below line from httpd.conf by removing "#"

> Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

3.Create a custom domain in the hosts file of your system

> sudo gedit /etc/hosts

4.Add Below line in hosts fils

> 127.0.0.5 www.myawesomeproject.com

5.Create your first virtual host

> sudo gedit /opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.5:80>
   DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/my-first-project"
   DirectoryIndex index.php
   <Directory "/opt/lampp/htdocs/my-first-project">
       Options All
       AllowOverride All
       Require all granted
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

6. Restart server by using below command.

> sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart